# How to do or where to get a good licence key generator

Tags: .net, licensing, key-generator

We have a software that is using an old dll for generating licence key. However, the person who used it left a while back and we are not sure this dll is even remotly safe or even if he has the right to use it. In other word, we would like replace it.

Does anybody know a good tool that could be used to create a key generator or sites on how to do so ? We would like to be able to create our own key generator program in .NET. Of course, it has to be secure enough that nobody will be able to generate the key without the interface itself. what we had before required to send a string and would return the key. This would do.

I am fully aware that a new Key generator will not gives the same result and am OK with that since we'll use it on the new version of the product.

Edit : Forgot to mention, the key we are using actuelly can indeed be reversed to get the original string. We put into this string information that we would like to retrieve and garbage. The key was 16 characters long Hexadecimal. This, however, can change if we need to do it.

Comment: What kind of keys is it generating?  Are they just random keys used to look something up?  Are they hashes?  Do they contain encrypted information?

Comment: Please see the edit for the answer.

Comment: that's highly insecure but if you're only dealing with inexpensive apps and inexperienced users then that's OK.  Any kind of rudimentary XOR-type encryption would probably do.  Bear in mind that anyone trying to crack the app will be able to do so very easily though.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, I am dealing here with an app developed by a 3rd tier party which wasn't so keen on security. That being said, the apps client are for most part really inexperience and we did set up a pretty good security for the software. The only downfall was the key itself, hence the reason we want to change it. What do you suggest for a really secure one ?

Comment: It depends on the app, but you could do something with public-key encryption: encrypt all the info using your private key, and use the public key to decrypt and validate it on the client.  No-one will be able to generate a valid key without your private key.  Only thing is the "licence key" would have to be long enough to store all the info needed.  Just one idea from the top of my head.  Hopefully others will suggest something practical.

Comment: This is actually a good start. One thing I did not mention though is the client app will never actually encrypt of decrypt. We keep the generator and validator to ourself.We send the client a key. When he activate the software, he send us the key back via a web service and we return true if the key is valid and false otherwise.

Comment: In that case, use a completely random key, and on the server store that key and the valid information associated with it.  someone would then have to (by luck) generate a random key, with a chance of millions/billions-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you are looking to prevent casual copying, almost any schema that binds the software to a single PC will work--there are a variety of commercial applications, including ours ([CodeMeter](http://www.wibu.us/codemeter)). If you're looking to prevent true piracy, the key generation is irrelevant because that's not how software is cracked. Typically a debugger is used to set a breakpoint at the license-checking routine; once the location in the assembly is found, the code is simply patched to always return a positive result. We call this ACOB (a couple of bytes) patching.

In .NET you can hack a program in less than 5 minutes using commonly-available tools (.NET Reflector, for example), unless the software has "true" protection.

Again, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. LIcensing can encompass creating and managing different business models (trial versions, pay per use, pay per user, net use, pay per feature, etc), anti-reverse engineering, anti-tampering (code integrity), and, of course, anti-piracy. Feel free to PM me if you need more info.

Comment: This is pretty interesting. Thank you. FYI, the software we are developing is a software for really specific type of client and preventing 'true' piracy is not really a concern. Licences are used for support and to track the number of users.

Comment: Assuming the number of users is pretty small then rolling your own is a perfectly sound idea. Paying for protection you don't need wouldn't be :) If the number of users is astronomic looking at something like Flexera might make sense (weak protection but good compliance tracking).